# Android: How to get JSON object keys from this json:

Tags: java, arrays, android-studio, json

This is the JSON array:

```
 {
    "server_response": [{
        "Total": "135",
        "Paid": "105",
        "Rest": "30"
    }]
}
```

So, how can i get the object names? I want to put them in separate TextView.
Thanks.

Comment: which names ?? "Total" and all ??

Comment: Take a look at this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm

Comment: @jankigadhiya i want all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this out side everything. I mean outside `onCreate()` and all.

```
private <T> Iterable<T> iterate(final Iterator<T> i){
    return new Iterable<T>() {
        @Override
        public Iterator<T> iterator() {
            return i;
        }
    };
}
```

**For getting the names of objects :**

```
    try
    {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("{" +"\"server_response\": [{" +"\"Total\": \"135\"," +"\"Paid\": \"105\"," +"\"Rest\": \"30\"" +"}]"+"}";);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response");
        JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

        for (String key : iterate(object.keys())) 
        {
            // here key will be containing your OBJECT NAME YOU CAN SET IT IN TEXTVIEW.
            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, ""+key, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks! This is what i want :)

Comment: One more thing, how can i set the keys in different textview?

Comment: give me the names of TextViews.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

Go to this website:

[Json to pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org)

Get your pojo classes and then use them in Android. 

All you need to do is to use Gson.fromGson(params here).
One of your params is the class that you created using the online schema.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jackson` `ObjectMapper` to do this.

```
public class ServerResponse {

 @JsonProperty("Total") 
 private String total;
 @JsonProperty("Paid") 
 private String paid;
 @JsonProperty("Rest") 
 private String rest;

 //getters and setters
 //toString()
}

//Now convert json into ServerResponse object
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
TypeReference<ServerResponse> serverResponse = new TypeReference<ServerResponse>() { };
Object object = mapper.readValue(jsonString, serverResponse);
 if (object instanceof ServerResponse) {
    return (ServerResponse) object;
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("Your JSON");
int Total = jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response").getJSONObject(0).getInt("Total");
int Paid = jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response").getJSONObject(0).getInt("Paid");
int Rest = jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response").getJSONObject(0).getInt("Rest");
```