# Parse JSON with both sides values

Tags: android, json

I'm using volley to get response from API but the response consist of STATE_ID:STATE_NAME pair `(i.e. value:value pair)` and I need both side's values in different Strings. I need these values to put in a spinner so that when user selects a `State` I can get its corresponding ID also.

```
// JSON response
{
  "1": "West bengal",
  "3": "Himachal Pradesh",
  "4": "Maharashtra",
  "11": "Queensland"
}
```

**My Code**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String STATE = "MY_API";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void login(View v){
        loginRequest();
    }
    private void loginRequest() {

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, STATE,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "VolleyError" + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("country_id","2");
                return params;
            }

        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

Comment: The JSON data contains Key-Value Pair, If you parse KEY then you will automatically get its VALUE. In your case ID seems like KEY and NAME seems like Value. So you know the ID strings, parse it as per selected ID

Comment: Usually when we parse key-value pair, we already know `key` and they don't change. Here the `IDs` will change. @OnkarNene

Comment: @SomnathPal see my answer here : [Android: How to get JSON object keys from this json:](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37323428/6127411)

Comment: I checked your answer but when I add the Iterator code outside onCreate(), I get this error `Class 'Anonymous class derived from Iterable' must be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'iterator()' in 'Iterable'`  @jankigadhiya

Comment: I imported `import java.util.Iterator;` which I think is sufficient @jankigadhiya

Comment: my method is not working @SomnathPal ?? should i post an answer ?? Corrected the method name please refer the answer again..!!

Comment: Its working but the toast only shows key pair. I want both key and the values. I'm also trying to put them into spinner @jankigadhiya

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have the `iterate()` method as we discussed in comments.

Done some work to give you value :

```
try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

        for (String key : iterate(jsonObject.keys()))
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Key : "+key+" Value: "+jsonObject.optString(key), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Please refer the `iterate` method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37323428/6127411). I have posted this as a new answer because OP was unable to make it for the values..!!

Answer (score 2):

I used iterator to find a key. May this will help:

```
 private void parseRespone(String response){

try {

JSONObject MainjsonObject = new JSONObject(response)

Iterator<String> iter= MainjsonObject.keys();
//To get keys of an object

    while (iter.hasNext()) 
    {

    String key = (String)iter.next();

            //Object value = jsonobj.get(key);  //To use by object

        String valueStr = jsonobj.get.getString(key);


    Log.i("Jsonparsing", "key= "+key + "\n Value=" +valueStr );

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"key= "+ key + "\n value= " + valueStr ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();        

    }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I could find an unknown key by this.
Please check in a Log in your android studio...
here I have put Toast also..

And call this function here...

```
...........
        @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

            parseRespone(response);  //Function to parse json

                    }
```

Thanks..

Comment: Can you show me how get both IDs and its values in your code using Toast? @Kush

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jsonObject.names()` (or `keys()` for an Iterator) to retrieve all keys.
After that you can iterate through the array using the keys and store your strings.

https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#names()
https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#keys()

Answer (score 1):

It will be much better if you consider changing your response to something like this:

```
[
  {"ID":"1","name": "West bengal"},
  {"ID":"3","name": "Himachal Pradesh"},
  {"ID":"4","name": "Maharashtra"},
  {"ID":"11","name": "Queensland"}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this solution and it worked out.`Here, "key" will toast the key_value[1,3,4,11] and value will print the names[West bengal,Himachal Pradesh,Maharashtra,Queensland].

JSONObject list_object = inner_json_object.getJSONObject("");

```
                for (String key : iterate(list_object.keys()))
                {
                    // here key will be containing your OBJECT NAME YOU CAN SET IT IN TEXTVIEW.
                    Toast.makeText(Activity.this, ""+key, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    String value = bank_list_object.optString(key);


                }`



private <T> Iterable<T> iterate(final Iterator<T> i){
    return new Iterable<T>() {
        @Override
        public Iterator<T> iterator() {
            return i;
        }
    };
}
```